# Trying to close an app through task scheduler delayed

Tags: batch-file

Cant get bat file to close L-Connect 3 which is my fan and rgb application that launches on boot and sets my lights and then is no longer needed until next cold start.

So far Ive tried this advice I got here for setting it as a schedule "No need to put this in a batch file. Just set "Program/script" to: taskkill, and set "Add arguments" to: /f /im programname.exe" which didnt work. I then saw someone recommend a bat file "taskkill /IM L-Connect 3.exe /F" and thats not working for me either, matter of fact running the bat file doesnt even close the app.

Tried this

```
 @echo off
 cd "C:\Program Files\LIAN_LI\L-Connect 3"
 Start "" /b L-Connect 3.exe
 timeout /T 5 /nobreak >nul
 taskkill /IM L-Connect 3.exe /F
```

it opens the black window and says it doesnt recognize " 3.exe" im so lost.  Basically I want task scheduler to close a program called L-Connect 3 a minute or 2 after login.  It launches fine through the apps settings but for the life of me I cant figure this out.  Any help to get this sorted.  The apps executable is called   "L-Connect 3"  Ive tried tasking the space away, I dont know.

Comment: if the name of the executable is `L-Connect 3.exe` you can try to call it like `"L-Connect 3.exe"`

Comment: Parenthesis did it, I knew I was missing something silly.  I had my hopes up on /pid because it worked first try only to realize L-connect had a different process ID each launch so I was at a loss until i read your response npocmoka ty so so much!!!